# C# Comparing dates with converted DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue with this piece of code it doesn't seem to work what I am doing wrong?

DepartureDate = DatePicked

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime seven = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+7);
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DepartureDate);

if (columnName == "DepartureDate")
{
    //range between today and seven days ahead +7
    if (dt >= today || dt <= seven)
    {
        result = valid;
        return result;
    }
    //can't be in the past
    if (dt < today)
    {
        result = "Can't be in the past";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your first condition checks if the date is after "today" _or_ before "in a week", which should be _all_ dates, right? A year ago is before "in a week" and a year from now is after "today", so both are valid.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if the departuredate is greater or equal to today or if departuredate is <= today + 7 days what I wanted is to to check weather the picked date is within this week or seven days ahead

Comment: I believe Joachim has identified the problem. If you want to avoid downvotes in the future, you should explain the problem rather than just saying "it doesn't seem to work".

Answer (score 2):

Your check for being within the range is using OR instead of AND.

Try changing:

```
if (dt >= today || dt <= seven)
```

to:

```
if (dt >= today && dt <= seven)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (dt >= today || dt <= seven)
```

to

```
if (dt >= today && dt <= seven)
```